# phpseclib TripleDES ECB issue

Tags: php, phpseclib, encryption-symmetric

I'm currently using phpseclib to encrypt data with tripleDES ECB. After using a third party online encryption tool I realized my encryption result differs from the  online tool's encryption result.

My code is attached as follows.

```
 $des = new \phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES('MODE_ECB');

 $des->setKey('cba4d056-1fab-4ce6-b61f-42e92e0dd563');
 $plaintext = 'abcabcabc';

 echo base64_encode($des->encrypt($plaintext));
```

The online encryption tool results are as follows.[image: Results from online encrpytion tool.]

What am I doing wrong with the library function that gives me a encrypted message different from the online tool shown?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is wrong. Do this instead:

```
$des = new \phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES(\phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES::MODE_ECB);
```